# 画像の高さを取得するとエラー AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python

pythonを始めたばかりの未熟者です。
画像の赤と青を入れ替えるというプログラムなのですが、下記のプログラムを実行すると

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exer1.py", line 15, in <module>
    H   = img.shape[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

となるのですがどう直せばいいのでしょうか
自分が手を加えたのはfor文の中だけなので改善するのはその中でお願いします。

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import cv2

fname_in  = sys.argv[1]
fname_out = sys.argv[2]

img = cv2.imread(fname_in)

H   = img.shape[0]
W   = img.shape[1]

for y in range(H) : 
    for x in    range(W) : 
        r = img[y,x,2]
        g = img[y,x,1]
        b = img[y,x,0]
        img[y,x,0] = r  
        img[y,x,2] = b
        # ここを編集

cv2.imwrite(fname_out, img )
```

Comment: 解決した場合、上矢印ボタンを押して賛成投票（役に立ったなら）して，チェックマーク✓でその回答を[承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) してください．回答者は嬉しいし，システム上もあなたの質問をもう解決したものとして扱えるようになります．「[自分の質問に誰か‌​が回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか?‌](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)​」も参照してください．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーメッセージでは`img = cv2.imread(fname_in)`で画像の読み込みに失敗したせいか、imgがNoneになっていると思われます。実行時の引数に存在している画像ファイルを渡しているか確認して見てください。

Comment: python exer1.py img_in.png a1_out.pngという実行コマンドを打ったのですがこれではだめでしょうか。読み込みたい画像ファイル名はimg_pngです。

Comment: すいません。解決できました。ありがとうございます